# Got error when I use Presto(in CDH cluster) query ADLS GEN2(Azure PASS, data lake) data

Tags: azure, presto, azure-data-lake-gen2

After mounting ADLS to the CDH cluster, I store the data from hive to ADLS, and then I want to use presto to query hive data, and an error is reported when querying the data stored in ADLS:

failed: No FileSystem for scheme: abfs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXXR0.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question to include specifics (such as code), as right now it's only a general description. Also, it's important to include properly-formatted text, not images of text. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which lists many reasons why this is  important.

Comment: presto doesn't have the hadoop-azure JAR with the abfs connector, and/or the right core-default config to read it. Which CDH version?